# How to accept soap requests with .NET Core 6

Tags: soap, asp.net-core-6.0

I need to convert an old soap service to .NET Core 6, so that it can reside with our other services on the same server.

I want to accept the soap request, content-type `application/soap+xml`, and then my code will process the request. Then it will return a response that is the same format, `application/soap+xml`.

I have looked all over the Internet and I can't quite get this to work. This is what I have so far, and I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 172).
>
> System.InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.

The request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                 xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
        <CoverageRequest xmlns="http://www.iicmva.com/CoverageVerification/">
            <RequestorInformation>
            </RequestorInformation>
            <Detail>
            </Detail>
        </CoverageRequest>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

My `program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IProcess, ProcessRepo>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISoapHelper, SoapHelper>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IData, VerifyDataRepo>();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

var config = builder.Configuration;

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My controller endpoint:

```
[ApiController]
public class DMVController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IProcess _process;

    public DMVController(IProcess process)
    {
        _process = process;
    }

    [Consumes("application/soap+xml")]
    [Produces("application/soap+xml")]
    [HttpPost, Route("/VerifyInsurance")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
        var returnValue = _process.ProcessRequest(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The .NET Core 6 `ApiController` is still, always and **only** a REST controller - it cannot directly handle SOAP calls - even if you send SOAP-compatible XML. If you need to call and talk to a SOAP web service from .NET Core, you need to check out the  [CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF) library

Comment: @marc_s Thank you for the reply. I am trying to avoid using other libraries for something simple. I only want the ability to receive a request with content-type application/soap+xml. This feature is only for one client and it will never change.  I will use CoreWCF if there is no other way, but is it possible to receive the request as a string or some other format in the body?

Comment: As I said - the `ApiController` is **REST** - always, 100% - you **CANNOT** use it to handle SOAP. If you need SOAP - use CoreWCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do what I needed without adding more dependencies to this project. I created a custom input format. I found an article that helped me [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

First, add the custom formatters in the program.cs file. SoapInputFormatter is my custom extension of the TextInputFormatter class:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new SoapInputFormatter());
});
```

In the SoapInputFormatter class you override CanReadType and ReadRequestBodyAsync:

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;

public class SoapInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    public SoapInputFormatter() 
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/soap+xml"));
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
       => type == typeof(string);

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
    {
        var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
        using var reader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body, encoding);
        try
        {
            var line = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(line);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return await InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot, I now have my request and I can process it.

[image: soap string is readable]

Answer (score 1):

Currently I'm converting an old VB.NET application that's using WCF/Soap. The CoreWCF library seems to do the trick for me.

https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF

I'd suggest you try to do something minimal at first, the walkthrough is great for that, to see if it fits your needs.

https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF/blob/main/Documentation/Walkthrough.md

Note that calling clients must use .NET Framework 4.6.2 or greater if you want to use TLS 1.2+.

PS SoapUI client also works like a charm with this library.